# Как запускать скрипт единожды в определенный месяц

Tags: python

Есть код, который проверяет урл на наличие. Допустим в месяц май и ноябрь. 1,2,3 числа скрипт не нашёл урл. 4-ого числа всё ок. Дальше целый месяц не запускаем его. Вплоть до ноября. И такая же логика для ноября. Подскажите алгоритм того как это можно реализовать по простому

Comment: cron - самое простое

Comment: Ну а как крон будет контролировать логику моего приложения?Г

Comment: Вы экономите на спичках. Скрипт будет запускаться каждый день. Но будет проверять наличие файла с датой успешного обновления. Если не прошёл месяц, дальнейшее выполнение скрипта завершается.